# ¿Como identar automáticamente en Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

En Java Netbeans lo ordeno con Alt+ Shift+F
Creo que en Dev es Ctrl + Shift + Z 
(Windows)

¿Pero en QT como lo hago? (No me funciona Ctrl + Shift + Z). Si tienen otros TIPS que me puedan ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Estoy con Ubuntu

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "ordenar el código"?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster creo que se refiere a identar el codigo

Comment: @x-rw yo prefiero que me digan las cosas, no suponerlas :(

Comment: Quiero darle format al código con alguna combinación teclas dentro de QT.
Se puede?

En Netbeans es Alt+ Shift+F o se puede seleccionar el código, click derecho luego en format.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con darle format al código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En mi caso, la combinación que venía por defecto es `CTRL + I`. En cualquier caso, como puedes ver en la imagen que sigue a estas líneas, es algo que puedes configurar a tu gusto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]